# AWS RDS event subscription with lambda in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I am trying to get lambda in another account to get it invoked by RDS instance event notifications. 
RDS event subscription is set to invoke SNS topic which triggers lambda in other account.

I have setup an entire stack using cloudformation. Things I achieved so far are

1. RDS events are able to invoke SNS topic, I have tested it using creating email subscription to SNS topic
2. SNS topic is able to trigger lambda in another account. I have tested it using publish messages in SNS topic. I can see that is flowing through in cloudwatch logs.

Part I am not able to get working is, RDS events triggering SNS and then Lamba in other account. Its very strage as individual bits are working fine but not end to end. Other observation is status of the SNS subscription in RDS events is shown as Active and I can see subscription log in lambda but nothing happens after I reboot RDS instance to test.

Also, I see this bizzare behaviour that subscription status is set to Null.

[image]

I followed below links for reference
https://jimmythompson.co.uk/blog/sns-and-lambda/
https://medium.com/pablo-perez/infrastructure-as-a-code-should-not-be-imperative-43d9a64e3998

Is there something I am missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? Im seeing the same thing.

Comment: Double and triple-check your SNS resource policy. In my case, my "resource" key in the policy is associated with an empty string due to an AWS management console bug when creating the SNS topic.